# Inline Asp.net Code is not triggering

Tags: asp.net

I have the following line of code:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/<%=Page.Theme%>/images/buttons/contractqv.png" NavigateUrl="javascript:showhideQuickView()"  ID="ShowHideBirdsEye" ToolTip="Show Hide Workload"></asp:HyperLink>
```

however when i run my code, and i look at the url, it becomes this:

```
http://localhost:51309/App_Themes/%3C%25=Page.Theme%25%3E/images/buttons/contractqv.png
```

Any idea why this is happening? i don't understand

Comment: try <%# Page.Theme %> along with DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is those characters can't be in a URL, so they get "encoded" to those weird values with %'s in them.  The <% %> isn't being interpreted as a command but just as more text

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ImageUrl=  '<%#ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}/images/buttons/contractqv.png", Page.Theme)) %>' NavigateUrl="javascript:showhideQuickView()"  ID="ShowHideBirdsEye" ToolTip="Show Hide Workload"></asp:HyperLink>
```

If the hyperlink is inside any data bound container, it will work fine. Else, you have to add this in `Page_Load`:

```
ShowHideBirdsEye.DataBind();
```

The code above is tested and working. Hope it helps!